# Suggestions for .Net 3D physics engine

Tags: c#, .net, physics, collision-detection, server-side

I need physics engine to simulate game world on server. I googled for .Net physics engines and they all were released in 2006-2009. So is there any good physics engine that I can use?

What I need from engine is box, spheres collisions..

**Update:** sorry forgot to mention i need 3d engine

**Update:** In case someone will need managed physics engine look at [Jitter](http://jitter-physics.com), it's pure managed and from the developer of JigLibX

Comment: " I googled for .Net physics engines and they all were released in 2006-2009" - why does that make them unapplicable?

Comment: I didn't say they are unapplicable.. but newer engines might be better optimized for multithreading as I think.

Comment: what evidence do you have for thinking that?

Comment: this is just my opinion.. ok so the question what engine can you suggest?

Comment: look at the ones you've already found, evaluate them, if none meet your needs, then post here with your findings (very useful for others). Just because an engine was posted in 2009 does not make it 'bad'!

Comment: @Mitch please stick to the topic, this is not a discussion about why it is better to go for a modern physics engine that is being actively maintained. You can start your own discussion group for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the very good Newton Game Dynamics via P/Invoke.

http://newtondynamics.com/forum/newton.php

There's also the well-regarded Bullet Physics engine, but I've never used it directly. It looks quite good, though.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bullet/

You weren't clear if you needed a purely managed code engine, but note these are not.

Answer (score 3):

2d Engine:

I had a look at this a little while ago: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

-- Edit: for some reason I'm unable to delete this comment myself, or even reply to comments, so I leave this edit in here. This answer was posted before the clarification of the requirement for 3D. If a mod wants to delete this, feel free.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention i need 3d engine

Answer (score 1):

free or commercial ?

free: jitter, jiglibX, henge3D, bulletX

commercial: bepu physics, matali physics, digitalrune physics

Answer (score 0):

I worked on one a few years back for a uni project

[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EkJlwvB3IQ)

[soureforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aphysicsengine/)

[codeexamples](http://apephysics.blogspot.com.au/)

MIT License 
Written natively in C#

It has some limitations as you would guess for a uni project

eg only use convex hulls

Features 
collision detection (uses bounding volume hierarchy)
elastic collisions
custom collision handling
also supports some particle physics and spatial queries (k-nearest neighbor).

its open source so if you wanted to add your own features to it you could