# Physics Engine for .Net/Mono

Tags: c#, physics-engine

I am looking for a .Net physics engine such as ODE, Bullet, Nvidia Physics Engine(Ageia), ...

If there is an implemention of the native physics engine, tell me plz.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggestions for .Net 3D physics engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631505/suggestions-for-net-3d-physics-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matali Physics: http://www.mataliphysics.com
It supports XNA, OpenTK, SlimDX out of the box.
free for non-commercial games

Comment: grammar errors on main site, very suspicios https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3bda1dsmiy4dh2f/syntax%20error%20%20%20mataly-physics.png

Answer (score 0):

There is Farseer at http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/.

If you want it for XNA (game) development, you may look at http://xnadevru.codeplex.com/, which is based on OPAL.

Comment: I use OpenTK *******************

Comment: Then I guess the XNA engine is not an option, maybe Farseer is.

Comment: Farseer.I guess it is a 2D Physic Engine.

Comment: Are you asking for a 3D physics engine?

Comment: Then please modify your question to make this explicit. The clearer your question, the better the answers you'll get.